# How to keep rendering data each time after ajax post?

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, express, client-server

Recently, I have learnt to deal with rendering data. But I am having a trouble to render sent data to ejs file in node.js. I wanted to use sent data for building my html page from server-side with embeded javascript(or jade). So in my code I save sent data in my file, it works pretty well. But problem is that the rendered data keeps being same as it was, even though the file is changed. I guess that the data is changed only once when I run server because my page changes when I rerun server. Please, share your tricks to overcome this kind of problems.

```
`enter code here`// ----- app.js
app.post('/notes' , function (req , res) {
    var fs = require('fs');
    var data = req.body;
    fs.writeFile("bucket.json" , JSON.stringify(data) , "utf8" , function (){});
});
// ---- routes/bucket
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    var data = require('bucket.json');
    res.render('bucket', {movies:data});
});
```

Comment: `require` reads the file once and caches it. Use `fs.readFile` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Modules are cached after the first time they are loaded. See https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_caching

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    fs.readFile('bucket.json', (err, data) => {
        if(err) {
            return next(err);
        }
        res.render('bucket', {movies:JSON.parese(data)});
    });
});
```

Comment: GREAT, that is it. Giant Thanks.